# Como passar dois argumentos na função onclick do JavaScript, programando em PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Eu tenho um botão que gero com AJAX e nesse mesmo botão tem um evento `onclick`, e quero passar dois argumentos para ele, porém estou tendo *bugs* com ele.

Código PHP:

```
 echo ' <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-comentario-reposta" id="botao-esconde-resposta-'.$_POST['id'].'"
            onclick="acao_botao_esconde_resposta('.$_POST['id'].','. $btn_mostrar_resposta .')">Esconder respostas</button>';
```

Aí mostra isso onde era pra estar o botão <kbd>Esconder respostas</kbd>.

Comment: esse `echo` é resultado de seu ajax ?

Comment: o echo é que vai ser retornado para o ajax escrever no html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu problema é que faltou escapar as `''` dos seus argumentos, corrigindo o seu código ele fica assim :

```
echo ' <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-comentario-reposta" id="botao-esconde-resposta-'.$_POST['id'].'"
            onclick="acao_botao_esconde_resposta(\''.$_POST['id'].'\',\''. $btn_mostrar_resposta .'\')">Esconder respostas</button>';
```

Como funciona :

Para escapar algum caracter especial como `""` as aspas ou  `''` aspas simples que usamos para passar argumentos dentro das funções usamos a `\` barra invertida para que no código ele considere o caracter como parte da string, um exemplo que pode esclacer melhor é o seguinte :

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$html = '<button id="btn-'.$id.'" onclick="func_teste('.$id.','.$email.')"></button>';
echo $html;
```

Esse exemplo assima seria o seu caso onde acontece o erro e porque  ? Bem quando esse código for para o html ele vai ser gerado dessa maneira por exemplo:

```
<!-- código html -->
<button id="btn-1" onclick="func_teste(1,email_teste@mail.com)"></button>
<!-- código html -->
```

Como podemos ver a passagem de parametro está errada e por isso seu código está imprimindo `)">Esconder respostas` para evitar esse problema tem de colocar as `\"\"` aspas ou  `\'\'` aspas simples para fazer seu escape e assim elas se tornam literal.

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$html = '<button id="btn-'.$id.'" onclick="func_teste(\''.$id.'\',\''.$email.'\')"></button>';
echo $html;
```

E o resultado será assim :

```
<!-- código html -->
<button id="btn-1" onclick="func_teste('1','email_teste@mail.com')"></button>
<!-- código html -->
```

Comment: mude os dois `.$_POST['id'].` para .$_POST["id"].

Comment: É isso mesmo, faltou escapar as aspas simples. +1

Comment: Qual seria o significado do uso da barra invertida e aspas simples?

Comment: @MuriloHass eu editei para responder ao seu comentário, desculpe se a edição n ficou muito boa mas é q eu fiz pelo celular ja que não estou perto de um computador

Comment: Eu entendi obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Pessoalmente acho que no seu caso é mais simples escrever o html como html e colocar apenas o que vem de php com `<?=`

```
<?php
$id = $_POST["id"];
?> 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-comentario-reposta" 
    id="botao-esconde-resposta-<?=$id?>"             
    onclick="acao_botao_esconde_resposta('<?=id?>','<?=$btn_mostrar_resposta?>')">
          Esconder respostas
</button>
```